# Like button just started showing duplicates. Has something changed on facebook's end?

Tags: facebook, duplicates, facebook-like

Sometime in the last few days all of the like buttons on my site are now showing duplicates and the spacing around them has changed so there is way too much space. Has something changed recently on facebook's end that would cause my code that used to work fine start behaving like this?

Here's an example link http://www.weddingwise.co.nz/vendor/kumeu-valley-estate. Scroll down a bit below the text on the left and you'll see the like button.

The code I'm using to produce the button is as follows:

```
<div class="fb-like"><fb:like show_faces="false" font="lucida grande"></fb:like></div>
```

And at the bottom of my body I have this code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: '150631368293357', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.type = 'text/javascript';
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

I also have open graph stuff on each page. Example of that matching the link above is:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Kumeu Valley Estate"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.weddingwise.co.nz/vendor/kumeu-valley-    estate/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.weddingwise.co.nz/images/uploads/vendor-thumbs/kumeuestate.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="WeddingWise.co.nz"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="150631368293357"/>
<meta property="og:description"content="Kumeu Valley Estate wedding vendor profile &amp; reviews on WeddingWise.co.nz"/>
```

This code was working fine before but just today I notice that the like buttons are duplicating like this. They appear to function fine though it's just the cosmetic problem of having two of them showing.

Is this a bug or has facebook made a change or what? What do I need to do to get them showing properly again?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I don't know why, but changing class name in `<div class="fb-like">` to `<div class="fblike">` fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

FYI adding class="fb-like" to **any** element causes this behaviour - in my case . I made the mistake of using this class name for adding padding to both  Facebook and Twitter button containers and ended up with 3 Facebook like buttons! So avoid using "fb-*anything*" for class names. Who knows what Facebook will do next?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think there is an unclosed tag that is causing it to get rendered twice because when I look at the source code there is obviously only one like button and I haven't seen other pages rendering this twice.  I would start by fixing alot of the html validation errors for the page listed [here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.weddingwise.co.nz/vendor/kumeu-valley-estate&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) or check your source control to make sure something else didn't get changed that caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Seems Facebook has updated their fb:like implementation script without telling anyone. It now adds a standard like button anywhere it finds class "fb-like"!!  Renaming the class fixes the issue.